# Setting particle emission at random keyframes?

Tags: particles, physics, keyframes, frame-rate

I'm  creating a physical simulation of apples falling into a box using the bullet particle system and Copy Particles to Rigid Bodies code by liero. However, the apples always fall in equal frame intervals according to the selected number of particles, frame start and end. is there any way to randomize the frame intervals?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with particles. Can you place your apples in the tree (with rigid body > active + dynamic disabled) and animate the "disabled" properties in the timeline to choose what apple start to fall?

Comment: I suppose I could "disable" apples randomly as a workaround if that's your direction. the problem is there are over 5,000 apples so doing it manually for each repetition (I need to run the simulation 10 times) will be imposible. maybe there's a way to code it.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution:

add to the emitter shape another geometry that is outside the camera viewport.
In this way emission is based on two different geometry and it really randomize the emission of the visible half of the mesh.

You can control the emission-ratio between the two island, by subdividing less or more the out-of-view mesh.

Check this video:

[image]

this (the meshes inside the purple line) is the same object:

[image]

Comment: great, thanks !